# Setting a variable for a view template

Tags: php, template

As you can see from the code below, my `set` function accepts two types of parameters:  either strings or arrays. Now, ideally I would like to be using operator overloading to handle this, but since PHP doesn't offer anything like that I am stuck with code like this. Is there a better way to write this (or perhaps a better way to address the problem altogether)?

```
class View {
   // stores file passed to View
   private $template;

   // setter function for template variables
   public function set($var, $content) {
      if (is_array($var) && is_array($content)) {
         if (sizeof($var) == sizeof($content)) {
            foreach ($var as $vari) {
               foreach ($content as $contenti) {
                  $this->template = str_replace("{" . "$vari" . "}", $contenti, $this->template);
               }
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         $this->template = str_replace("{" . "$var" . "}", $content, $this->template);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a simple way to flatten out those loops, but it is not what I would suggest.  Here is the simple way:

```
if ((sizeof($var) == sizeof($content))) {
    $count = sizeof($var);

    for ($i =0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $this->template = str_replace(
            '{' . $var[$i] . '}', $content[$i], $this->template);
    }
}
```

Note that you are currently silently doing nothing when the size of your arrays don't match.  I think that is a bug.

### My Suggestions

`$var` and `$content` are not very descriptive: I would suggest `$match` and `$replacement`.

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) can handle arrays as input.  I would suggest filling your match with the '{' and '}' beforehand.  The code then becomes:

```
public function set($match, $replacement)
{
   $this->template = str_replace($match, $replacement, $this->template);
}
```

I would place any sanity checks before the str_replace that you require.  str_replace uses blank replacements when the matches array is larger than the replacements.  If you want to avoid that use:

```
   if (is_array($match) && is_array($replacement) &&
       sizeof($match) > sizeof($replacement))
   {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(
         __METHOD__ . ' Each match must have a replacement');
   }
```

This avoids [arrow code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) which will make the code easier to test, reduce its complexity and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea I could pass arrays directly into `str_replace` and it would handle the iteration for me behind the scenes! Additionally, I believe you forgot to include the third parameter in your str_replace function; shouldn't it read: `$this->template = str_replace($match, $replacement, $this->template);`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_replace_callback` to iterate through your array and replace any data.

```
public function set($data){ // data = array

    $callback = function ($matches) use ($data)
    {
            return ( isset($data[$matches[1]]) ) 
               ? $data[$matches[1]] 
               : $matches[0];
    };

     return preg_replace_callback(
                '/\{(.*?)\}/', 
                $callback, 
                $this->template);
}
```